# Custom Attribute that can generate compile time error

Tags: c#, attributes, compiler-errors

I have an interface:

```
public interface IBaseInterface
{
    void Base();
}
```

And I use use it like:

```
public class BaseClass : IBaseInterface
{
    public void Base()
    {

    }
}
```

However, I want to implement an attribute such that:

```
public class BaseClass : IBaseInterface // Generates Compile-Time Error
{
    public void Base()
    {

    }
}
```

I only want to be able to use the interface like this:

```
public interface IAdditionalBaseInterface : IBaseInterface
{

}

public class AdditionalBaseClass : IAdditionalBaseInterface // No Compile-Time Error
{
    public void Base()
    {

    }
}
```

Is it possible to have a custom `Attribute` which does this? I am aware of the `ObsoleteAttribute` but was wondering how this even works, or more so, how I can implement my own which has the same compile-time error functionality.

Comment: Note that the ObsoleteAttribute cheats and uses compiler magic to achieve what it does.  You can't do this yourself.

Comment: @TrevorElliott It's not that I don't believe you, I don't believe anyone without concrete proof or documentation to back up their statement. Any additional links you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: I found that information already by searching similar questions to yours.  You can too.

Comment: @gleng: you can't implement method `Base` in class `Base`. What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear.

Comment: I don't think you can create such an attribute.
What you can do instead is create a build task that runs after the compilation and checks the assembly through reflection.

Comment: @Dennis Edited. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObsoleteAttribute` is hardcoded in the compiler, you won't be able to have the same behavior. Also do note it generates a compile-time warning, or an error if the `IsError` property of the attribute is set to `true`.

What you probably could do is a custom Code Analysis (FxCop) rule, that will do the reflection/introspection job on build. But it won't be as easy to use as an attribute.

See http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html for the FxCop SDK

Not sure what would be a useful use case anyway, this kind of defeats the OOP concepts.

Comment: +1 For detailed answer.

Comment: @gleng You're totally right, I edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Linq to SQL / Object.  If you (for instance) use EF6, and create a bool version of a char yes/no property to make coding easier elsewhere, you cannot use that in a .Where that calls down to the database, but you can use it in a .Where after a .ToList().  A compiler error would be helpful at that point.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to install this NuGet package:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/PostCompile/0.1.0-alpha

Upon installing it will extend the project targets by another post-compile task and add a little assembly to your project. The added post-compile task will load your compiled assembly, scan for types deriving from `PostCompileTask` and execute the run method.

In your project you add a new class deriving from the `PostCompileTask` class. You then override the Run() method that that gets passed your compiled assembly, and a helper object for logging. Within this run method you can (using reflection) scan your assembly for the custom attribute. When you find it, you can call the `Error()` method of the logging helper. This will result in an error within the Visual Studio error window, and the rest of the build process stops.